# LightGallery with JqueryMobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, lightgallery, lightgallery-2

I have a little problem with LightGallery plugin ([lightGallery - Git](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/)). I use jQueryMobile.

My gallery is on a specific page. When I arrive on this page, it will request a remote server to get some pics.

Then I initialize LightGallery. No problem the first time.

But **when I leave the Gallery Page and come back after** (there is a new request to server), lightGallery is not running.

No error in the browser, I have my photos displayed but I can't click on it to run LightGallery like I've done the first time.

My Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageGallery" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content" class="center-body">
        <h3 class="nomGroupe"></h3><br/>
        <div class="demo-gallery">
            <ul id="lightgallery" class="list-unstyled row">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javscript :**

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function ( event, ui ) {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );
  if (activePage[0].id == "pageGallery" ) {
    $('#lightgallery').empty();
    $(".groupName").empty().append("group "+localStorage['groupName']);
    envoieRequete('http://myServer/', {'idGroup' : localStorage['idGroup'], 'token' : localStorage['token']}, 'post', function(output){
        if(output.group.photos.length === 0) {
            $("#lightgallery").append('<br/><p>Empty for Group : ' + localStorage['groupName']+'</p>');
        }
        else {
            for(i=0; i<output.group.photos.length; i++) {
                $('#lightgallery').append('<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="http://myServer/'+localStorage['token']+'/'+localStorage['idGroup']+'/' + output.group.photos[i].id
                + '" data-src="http://myServer/'+localStorage['token']+'/'+localStorage['idGroup']+'/' + output.group.photos[i].id + '" data-sub-html="<h4>PhotoAlt</H4>"><a href=""><img class="img-responsive"\n\
                src="http://myServer/'+localStorage['token']+'/'+localStorage['idGroup']+'/' + output.group.photos[i].id + '"/></a></li>');
            }
        }
    });
  }
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
    switch (activePageId) {
        case 'pageGallery':
           $(document).on("tap", "#lightgallery li", function (){
                 $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({});
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using wrong html markup. you can check the following code for reference. This is sample code.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3" id="lightgallery">
      <li> <a class="item" href="img/alchemy_icon1.jpg"><img src="img/alchemy_icon1_th.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li> <a class="item" href="img/chandra1.jpg"><img src="img/chandra1-th.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li> <a class="item" href="img/Fish.jpg"><img src="img/Fish-th.jpg"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#lightgallery").lightGallery({
    selector: '.item'
});
```